UART Transmission Incorrect on ATTiny826
I'm currently trying to test an extremely simple circuit where I use an ATTiny86 to output some arbitrary values via serial to an Arduino micro. The problem I am facing is that all of the values being written to the TX pin of the device are wrong. I am using an oscilloscope to measure the values as well as the arduino micro.
The oscilloscope images attached display what I am seeing when I measure the Tx/Rx line between the ATTiny and the Micro. Basically, the values that I try to send are not being sent correctly. The actual waveform looks alright, but the binary representation as measured by the scope and the micro are the same incorrect value. I have some examples shown below:
I cannot for the life of me figure out why the data is being corrupted in such a way. I've added extra images to hopefully help someone decode why this is happening.
Sent: [01 02 03 A5 FF 7E] --> Recieved [C1 D0 58 FA 9E]

Sent: 0xAA (0b10101010) --> Recieved: 0xB4 (0b10110100)

Sent: 0x55 (0b01010101) --> Recieved: 0x8B (0b10001011)

Sent: 0x81 (0b10000001) --> Recieved: 0xA1 (0b10100001)

Simplified Schematic:

Code on Attiny
#include <Arduino.h>

#define LED_PIN PIN_PC3

void setup() {
    // Initialize Serial1 communication at 19200 baud rate (or adjust as needed)
    Serial1.begin(19200, SERIAL_8E1);
}

void loop() {
    // Array of hexadecimal values to send
    uint8_t hexArray[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0xA5, 0xFF, 0x7E};  // Example hex values

    // Loop through the array and write each value to Serial1
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(hexArray); i++) {
        Serial1.write(hexArray[i]);  // Write each value to Serial1
    }

    // Add a delay to avoid flooding Serial1
    delay(1000);  // 1 second delay
}



you don't have the grounds connected

why do you believe that the problem is with the transmitted data?

@jstola grounds are connected as USB and ATTiny are run on same power/gnd net. Even with GND connected directly I get the same results.
I believe it's due to the transmission of the data because I am recieving the same incorrect results on both the Micro and via the oscilloscope. I have had success reading the UART of an UNO and Micro via the same oscilloscope, same code, same settings, but it does not work with the ATTiny.

the oscilloscope pictures show correct data ... the baud rate may be too high ... try lowering the baud rate

I tried lowering it down to 9600 and 2400 but I still get exactly the same data in the oscilloscope and micro. I also tried increasing it to 115200 and got the same effect.

set the baud rate to 18000? ... I can't run a test right now to see if it is a valid value ... leave the receiver  at 19200

@jstola, That almost seems to have worked. I changed it to 18000, no dice, but then I changed it to 16000 and it worked. My thinking now is that the ATTiny Clock is set to 20Mhz but platformIO is assuming it is using the 16MHz internal clock. The ratio of 16:20 is 0.8; 0.8 * 19200 = 15360, and it seems to work at this baud rate. Does this sound like I'm on the right track?

You are sending 11 bits per transmission, 1 start bit, 8 data bits, 1 even parity bit, and 1 stop bit. The records and the source show it.
The time to send 10 bits (start bit to parity bit) can easily be read from the single byte transmissions. It is about 415 µs. So the time for one bit is about 41.5 µs.
The time to send 6 bytes 11 bits each = 66 bits is about 2750 µs. So the time for one bit is again about 41.5 µs.
The reciprocal value gives us the baudrate, which is about 24100 bits per second. The oscilloscope's serial decoder and the Arduino's UART expect a standard baudrate, most probably you use 19200. No surprise that they interpret the bits as other values, as they sample the line at different times.
Therefore, the system clock of your ATtiny826 is not what the compiler thinks it is. Check that, and correct it.
The transmission is not corrupted, all bits are exactly as they should. It is just the speed, derived from the ATtiny's clock.

Thanks! I set the board clock in platformio.ini by updating the line:
board_build.f_cpu = 20000000L
I must have told the device to use the 20MHz internal clock instead of the 16MHz internal when I set up the updi programmer. This is now working as intended.

@PatrickVoorhoeve The quotients match. Perfect!
